# Receiving android notifications on the terminal

Tags: android, terminal, push-notification, notifications, pushbullet

I want to get all the notifications from my android phone on the linux terminal when I run certain commands. For example, if I have a WhatsApp and a email notification then I should receive this data on the terminal. If there is no notification then it should reply with no notification.

I need this for a project. I read Pushbullet API docs and was not able to figure out a way to do it using that. I was able to send a notification from terminal to my android but not the opposite. What tool can I use?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: I don't think its possible to read notifications of other Apps.

Comment: @Akshay Just the notification app, like if it from whatsapp then it may show that a whatsapp notfication is present

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution for this two months back but forgot that I had posted a question here. So, the solution is creating a websocket client to interact with the pushbullet servers which in-turn have the log of all the notification that we are receiving on our android phone. [websocket-client in python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client)